# Query to find out total patients for 15 days

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a question . I have a query which finds out the number of patients in that particular day

```
Select wtt1.wrt_ip_num, wtt1.wrt_from_ward_cd, wbm.wbm_room_num, wbm.wbm_bed_num, wtt1.wrt_in_dt, wtt1.wrt_out_dt
FROM W_TRANSFER_TXN wtt1, w_ward_master_base wmb, w_bed_master_base wbm
where wtt1.wrt_from_ward_cd=wmb.wwm_ward_cd and wmb.wwm_ward_locn='TMH' 
  and wbm.wbm_bed_num=wtt1.wrt_from_bed_num and wbm.wbm_room_num=wtt1.wrt_from_room_num and wbm.wbm_ward_cd=wtt1.wrt_from_ward_cd 
  and (wtt1.wrt_ip_num, wtt1.wrt_sl_num ) in 
    (Select wtt.wrt_ip_num, max(wtt.wrt_sl_num) wrt_sl_num 
    FROM W_TRANSFER_TXN wtt
    where /*wtt.wrt_ip_num='IP/20/034619' and*/ trunc(wtt.wrt_in_dt)<=TO_DATE('29-Sep-2020','DD-MON-YYYY') 
          and (wtt.wrt_out_dt is null or trunc(wtt.wrt_out_dt)>=TO_DATE('29-Sep-2020','DD-MON-YYYY'))
    group by wtt.wrt_ip_num);
```

Currently it takes out the ip number for the date 29th . It gives the no. of IP nums for that particular date.
What I want to do is take this whole query in a loop where it finds out the query for the previous 15 days. Is that possible . Can the whole query be looped for the previous 15 days?
Can we put in a loop where the date field is?
I can take out the number of patients everyday by changing the date but can I find that out for 15 days?

Comment: This is the query can we put in a loop where the date is?

Comment: Why do you want to use a loop and send 15 queries instead of one query where you get all data of the whole 15 days? Also, are you able to "declutter" your query so it's way more readable and has no obsolete information (for us)? I'd use `trunc(wtt.wrt_in_dt) between to_date('29.....') and to_date('14.....')`.

Comment: The whole query is developed to give the value for 1 date can the whole query be put in a loop?

Comment: The in date and out date are for patients who have stayed and left on that day

Comment: `where trunc(wtt.wrt_in_dt) between TO_DATE('29-Sep-2020','DD-MON-YYYY')-15 and TO_DATE('29-Sep-2020','DD-MON-YYYY') and (wtt.wrt_out_dt is null or trunc(wtt.wrt_out_dt)>=trunc(wtt.wrt_in_dt))`?

Comment: Do a crossjoin with calendar generated with connect by or recursive CTE and "multiply" your result by any of the day count with little overhead in logic. But if you really want a well-performing query, then extract the desired logic from your query, place some example data in your question and ask exactly what you need and not "parse my code and try to find out the place to modify"..

Comment: Join over WHERE clause is very hard to read, so you also should rewrite your code to JOINs to make it pretty-looking.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you fixed the `wtt.wrt_in_dt` to `date '2020-09-29'`, query returns data for that particular date.

Consider changing the condition to

```
trunc(wtt.wrt_in_dt) >= trunc(sysdate) - 15
```

which will return rows whose `wrt_in_dt` is within the last 15 days.

---

How to generate dates?

```
SQL> select date '2020-10-20' + level - 1 datum
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= 5;

DATUM
----------
20.10.2020
21.10.2020
22.10.2020
23.10.2020
24.10.2020

SQL>
```

---

If you want to use dates in a `FOR` loop, you'll have to do a "conversion" to a **Julian** date (whose datatype is `NUMBER`) as `FOR` loop won't allow dates as *boundaries*. It also means that you'd have to convert that Julian date back to be used in query. I don't have any suitable table so`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` will have to do.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_datum         DATE := TRUNC (SYSDATE);
  3     l_datum_julian  NUMBER := TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (l_datum, 'j'));
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR i IN l_datum_julian .. l_datum_julian + 5
  6     LOOP
  7        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (i, 'j'), 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
  8     END LOOP;
  9  END;
 10  /
16.10.2020
17.10.2020
18.10.2020
19.10.2020
20.10.2020
21.10.2020

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Actually the whole query is geared up for the date can we put in a loop?

Comment: In PL/SQL, yes - use any loop you want. In SQL, a "loop" (kind of) can be done using CONNECT BY and the LEVEL pseudocolumn (you'd add LEVEL to some starting date).

Comment: can you give an example of that

Comment: If you mean "how to generate dates", then I edited the answer and added an example.

Comment: no no i want to have a for loop where I am giving the dates in the where clause

Comment: In a FOR loop? OK, I added another example.

Comment: This is not what I want I wanted the for loop in the where clause in the query. However I have upvoted your answer because of the help